# Meta analysis Cliff's delta

Tags: nonparametric, meta-analysis, normality-assumption, cohens-d

Cliff's delta is an effect size typically recommended whenever the normality and homogeneity assumption do not hold---and thus, Cohen's d cannot be used.

However, I cannot see any reference indicating how to calculate its standard error, or how to run a meta analysis with Cliff's delta.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use, or at least can read, R then there are at least two packages which can help which compute Cliff's $\delta$ and its sampling variance.

effsize  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=effsize

orddom https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=orddom

Once you have the standard errors then there seems no special step needed to compute meta-analysis in the standard inverse variance weighted way.